# Get TabHost default system color

Tags: android, colors, android-tabhost, gradient

I don't want to change the TabHost i just want to get the first gradient color of the tab button when selected (the light blue  in Samsung's TouchWiz for example)

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured that I can use this to get the background drawable...

```
tabWidget.getBackground();
```

...but not the color themselves as the background is an image.